# How to get all values from a Model instance on django

Tags: django

I'm using django signals with post_save and receiving an instance:

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=ServiceOrder)
def service_order_post_save(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        print(instance)
```

I just want to get all values from this instance without doing field per field (is a big Model).

I tried:

```
instance.objects.values()
instance.values()
list(instance)
```

as expected all trys failed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just serialize your instance. You can try this.

```
from django.core import serializers

@receiver(post_save, sender=ServiceOrder)
def service_order_post_save(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        data = serializers.serialize('json', [instance,])
        print(data)
```